# Flutter, Trying to play downloaded mp3 file which is in app directory but No such file or directory exception

Tags: flutter

Trying to play mp3 file which my app Download from somewhere, but I cannot open this file. Even i cannot find Acutual path which the mp3 file can be taken.

in android
getExternalStorageDirectory

in iOS
getExternalStorageDirectory,

using that..( assume Android)

It seems that mp3 file is successfully downloaded in to

/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/my_app_id/files/some.mp3

I can see  that file in android 'File app' path is
/internal storage/Download/some.mp3

i am not sure both path means same.

### anyway I am trying to open this file

void accessMP3File(String url) async {

```
File file = File(url);

if (await file.exists()) {
   // exist
} else {

  // The file does not exist
}
```

}

no matter which path is, always file dose not exist.

Eventually, I cannot play it.

ps-
READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions are taken by permission_handler. and  audio player is audio_service

Comment: try to add the following permission and also tell what audio player you are using. 

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: those permission are gained by permission_handler. and audio player is 'audio_service'